# Facebook native 5 ads show on Recyclerview in android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, native-ads

When i use this below link facebook native ads adapter it shows multiple ads in recyclerview how to set 5 ads in recyclerview.

https://github.com/fbsamples/audience-network/tree/master/samples/android/AdsSample/app/src/main/java/com/facebook/audiencenetwork/adssample

if apply:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // return position % AD_DISPLAY_FREQUENCY ==0 ? AD_TYPE : POST_TYPE;
    if (position == 0 || position == 5 || position == 10 || position == 15 || position == 20) {
        return AD_TYPE;
    }
    return POST_TYPE;
}
```

show items duplicate after position 20.please help....

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicate after position 20"?

Comment: when i put getitemViewType position 25... show ads ,but  i am not giving ads at positon 25...,  so it places duplicate item at position 25...